# How do I change the size of the View tag depending on the orientation of the device in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been using this code

```
`import { StyleSheet, 
        Text, 
        View,
        SafeAreaView,
        Platform,
        StatusBar,
        Button,
        Image,
        Dimensions } 
        from 'react-native';
import { useLayout, 
        useDeviceOrientation } 
        from '@react-native-community/hooks';

export default function App() {
  const { landscape } = useDeviceOrientation;
  const { portrait } = useDeviceOrientation();
  console.log(useDeviceOrientation());
  console.log(Dimensions.get('screen'));
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
          width: landscape ? "100%": "100%",
          height: landscape ? "100%":"30%"
        }}
      ></View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
`
```

I've tried taking out the landscape condition in the width and switching around the proportions in the height. I have also tried to add flex but that didn't work either.